# Objective C - Altering appearance of control implementing appearance api

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I am using the appearance api to customize `UISearchBar`

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:searchBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setScopeBarBackgroundImage:backgroundImage];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

I am using this in a class that is a parent to other classes so that the effect is implemented on all **child** classes.

Now I need to customize one of the subclass containing `UISearchBar`. I tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936566/can-background-or-borders-be-removed-from-uisearchbar)

But I can't get that effect when the appearance is done on **superclass**. If I remove the **appearance** then I am able to have this effect.

How can I do this by implementing **appearance** api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn%3a)

```
    [[UISearchBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[yourSubClassedViewControllerWhichHasSearchbar class], nil]
     setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using following code

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

for (id img in srchbar.subviews) {
    if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [img removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Above solution can cause the others to display wrong. So the best solution is marked as right.